# How to do post-mortem debugging within Django's runserver?

Tags: python, django, pdb, ipdb, postmortem-debugging

I am currently debugging a Django project which results in an exception. I would like to enter the `ipdb` post-mortem debugger. I've tried invoking `ipdb` as a script (cf. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), but this just enters me to the first line of code:

```
> python -m ipdb manage.py runserver
> /Users/kurtpeek/myproject/manage.py(2)<module>()
      1 #!/usr/bin/env python
----> 2 import os
      3 import sys

ipdb>
```

If I press `c` to `continue`, I just run into the error, with no possibility to drop into the debugger post-mortem. Presumably I could press `n` (`next`) until I get the error, but that would be quite cumbersome.

Is there a way to run `python manage.py runserver` with post-mortem debugging?

Comment: Exceptions in Django are nearly all handled. So, they never reach the debugger. You should set a breakpoint on the `raise` line for the exception, or as close as possible to it on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you know of a line that causes the exception, but don't know how "deep" inside it the exception is caused, you can get a post-mortem debugger for it by catching the exception and calling `ipdb.post_mortem()` in the exception handler.

For example, change your code from this:

```
def index(request):
    output = function_that_causes_some_exception()
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

To this:

```
def index(request):
    try:
        output = function_that_causes_some_exception()
    except:
        import ipdb
        ipdb.post_mortem()
        # Let the framework handle the exception as usual:
        raise
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

By the way, for server frameworks that could be spewing stuff in the console from other threads I highly recommend [`wdb`](https://github.com/Kozea/wdb), so that you can debug your django app from the comfort of a browser:

```
def index(request):
    try:
        output = function_that_causes_some_exception()
    except:
        import wdb
        wdb.post_mortem()
        # Let the framework handle the exception as usual:
        raise
    return HttpResponse(output)
```